# Is there a possibility to change content of DataGridRowGroupHeader control?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I'm using DataGrid control from WindowsCommunityToolkit and I want to fully localize this control.

I found option to change grouping category name (RowGroupHeaderPropertyNameAlternative property), but I can't find any to change phrase that tell how many items is in the grouped category (string "x items" to other word) in the same view.

Is there some control template or property to get custom text in DataGridRowGroupHeader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I can't find any to change phrase that tell how many items is in the grouped category (string "x items" to other word) in the same view.

The [WindowsCommunityToolkit](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit) is open source. You actually could download it and check the DataGrid source code. What you mentioned about 'string x items' is specified in its C# code. You could see this [line](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/DataGrid/DataGridRowGroupHeader.cs#L673).

```
if (_itemCountElement != null && this.RowGroupInfo != null && this.RowGroupInfo.CollectionViewGroup != null)
{
        _itemCountElement.Text = string.Format(
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                this.RowGroupInfo.CollectionViewGroup.GroupItems.Count == 1 ? Properties.Resources.DataGridRowGroupHeader_ItemCountSingular : Properties.Resources.DataGridRowGroupHeader_ItemCountPlural,
                this.RowGroupInfo.CollectionViewGroup.GroupItems.Count);
 }
```

The string format template is defined in resource file:

[image]

So, if you want to localize it by yourself, you could start from this point. And compile a custom DataGrid version for your project.